# Color by group and legend in plot3D

Tags: r, colors, plot3d

I'm trying to create my own 3D histogram using `plot3D`, so I took a look at [this page](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization) as a starter before applying it on my own data. The code is clear and straightforward enough but I wonder how I can group rows of data (formatted as matrix indices in the example `VADeaths` data) into fewer categories (e.g., 50-54 & 55-59 --> "Fifties", 60-64 & 65-69 --> "Sixties", 70-74 --> "> 70") and assign them to different colors (e.g, "Fifties: blue", "Sixties: yellow", "> 70: white")? And, also, to have this information displayed on the legend to the right of the 3D plot?

Below is a working example listed on the reference page.

```css
# install.packages("plot3D")
library(plot3D)

data(VADeaths)
# plotting
hist3D (x = 1:5, y = 1:4, z = VADeaths,
        bty = "g", phi = 20,  theta = -60,
        xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "", main = "VADeaths",
        col = "#0072B2", border = "black", shade = 0.8,
        ticktype = "detailed", space = 0.15, d = 2, cex.axis = 1e-9)
        
# label x axis: age group (this part is to be sorted into fewer categories)
 text3D(x = 1:5, y = rep(0.5, 5), z = rep(3, 5),
       labels = rownames(VADeaths),
       add = TRUE, adj = 0)
       
# label y axis: gender by urbal/rural residency
 text3D(x = rep(1, 4),   y = 1:4, z = rep(0, 4),
       labels  = colnames(VADeaths),
       add = TRUE, adj = 1)
```

[image]

I've referenced this [earlier post](https://www.biolinfo.com/histrograms-in-plot3d/) but can't seem to understand it.
It'll be really appreciated if someone could share some tips on this.